# Crear una lista de numeros aleatorios en python

Tags: python, lista, random

estoy intando crear una lista de numeros aleatorios en python.
Logre crearla pero solo quiero que me aparenzan numeros de tipo int() y me aparecen todos de tipo float(), alguien sabe que puedo hacer? Esto es lo que hce:

```
import random
def listaAleatorios(n):
      lista = [0]  * n
      for i in range(n):
          lista[i] = random.random()
      return lista

print("Ingrese cuantos numeros aleatorios desea obtener")
n=int(input())

aleatorios=listaAleatorios(n)
print(aleatorios)
```

Answer (score 5):

Usa `random.randint` en lugar de `random.random` ya que esta última retorna valores pseudoaleatorios entre 0.0 y 1.0. Pero ten en cuenta que has de especificar el rango en el que quieres que estén dichos números aleatorios, `randint` recibe dos parámetros, el primero es el límite inferior del rango y el segundo el superior, ambos pueden salir elegidos.

```
import random

def listaAleatorios(n):
      lista = [0]  * n
      for i in range(n):
          lista[i] = random.randint(0, 1000)
      return lista

print("Ingrese cuantos numeros aleatorios desea obtener")
n=int(input())

aleatorios=listaAleatorios(n)
print(aleatorios)
```

O simplemente:

```
import random


print("Ingrese cuantos numeros aleatorios desea obtener")
n=int(input())
aleatorios = [random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(n)]
print(aleatorios)
```

en este caso se obtienen números aleatorios entre 0 y 1000, si quieres otro rango pásaselo a `randint` según tus necesidades.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias!! Me quedo con la primera porque necesitaba hacer una funcion

Answer (score 0):

Crea una lista con números aleatorios y que estos no se repitan:

```py
from random import randint 

listado_numeros = [] # crea una lista para almacenar los numero rondón sin repetir.
contador_rondas = 0 # almacena las veces que se agrega un numero a la lista.

numero_random = randint(1,30) # genera un numero rondón de 1 entre 30

# se repite hasta que el tamaño de la lista no llegue a 5 (para el caso que solo quiera 5 numero).
while contador_rondas < 5:
    numero_random = randint(1,30) # genera un numero rondón de 1 entre 30
    if numero_random in listado_numeros: # verifica si el número rondón ya se encuentra en la lista
        pass
    else:
        listado_numeros.append(numero_random) # agrega el número a la lista
        contador_rondas = contador_rondas + 1 # suma a cada vuelta
        
print(listado_numeros)

>>> [25, 21, 30, 15, 27]
```

Answer (score -1):

También puede ser útil utilizar `random.randrange`, que además de devolver enteros, agrega un salto en el rango.

Por ejemplo, en caso de necesitar sólo enteros pares:

```
import random

def listaAleatorios(n):
    lista = []
    for i in range(n):
        lista.insert(i, random.randrange(0, 1000, 2))
    return lista

print("Ingrese cuantos numeros aleatorios desea obtener")
n = int(input())

aleatorios = listaAleatorios(n)
print(aleatorios)
```